# Pivot data from duplicate or triplicate rows

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, pivot

Hi I need to set up an SSIS package to import data from experiments (excel files) that are run in duplicate and triplicate this will be done on a multitude of files so it needs to be fully automated. I only need help with the data flow task not the foreach loop container task.

The table I have looks like this:

| Well | Well Position | Omit | Sample Name | Target Name | Task | Reporter | Quencher | CT | Ct Mean | Ct SD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | C1 | FALSKT | PK | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 30,412 | 30,561 | 0,180 |
| 26 | C2 | FALSKT | PK | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 30,511 | 30,561 | 0,180 |
| 27 | C3 | FALSKT | PK | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 30,761 | 30,561 | 0,180 |
| 28 | C4 | FALSKT | 20-53552 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 28,963 | 28,996 | 0,047 |
| 29 | C5 | FALSKT | 20-53552 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 29,029 | 28,996 | 0,047 |
| 30 | C6 | FALSKT | 20-53569 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 31 | C7 | FALSKT | 20-53569 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 32 | C8 | FALSKT | 20-53570 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 22,071 | 22,010 | 0,087 |
| 33 | C9 | FALSKT | 20-53570 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 21,948 | 22,010 | 0,087 |
| 34 | C10 | FALSKT | 20-53575 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 30,067 | 30,092 | 0,036 |
| 35 | C11 | FALSKT | 20-53575 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 30,118 | 30,092 | 0,036 |
| 36 | C12 | FALSKT | 20-53577 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 37 | D1 | FALSKT | 20-53577 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 38 | D2 | FALSKT | 20-53584 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 33,937 | 33,864 | 0,103 |
| 39 | D3 | FALSKT | 20-53584 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 33,792 | 33,864 | 0,103 |
| 40 | D4 | FALSKT | 20-53585 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 41 | D5 | FALSKT | 20-53585 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 42 | D6 | FALSKT | 20-53586 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 43 | D7 | FALSKT | 20-53586 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 44 | D8 | FALSKT | NTC rdrp | xb | NTC | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 45 | D9 | FALSKT | NTC rdrp | xb | NTC | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |
| 46 | D10 | FALSKT | NTC rdrp | xb | NTC | FAM | None | Undetermined |  |  |

As you can see under sample name there are samples that are run in duplicates and triplicates.

What I would like in the destination table would be this: Where the columns for CT, Well and Well position are pivoted so that each sample only has one row.

| Well | Well2 | Well3 | Well Position | Well Position2 | Well Position3 | Omit | Sample Name | Target Name | Task | Reporter | Quencher | CT | CT2 | CT3 | Ct Mean | Ct SD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 26 | 27 | C1 | C2 | C3 | FALSKT | PK | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 30,412 | 30,511 | 30,761 | 30,561 | 0,180 |
| 28 | 29 |  | C4 | C5 |  | FALSKT | 20-53552 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 28,963 | 29,029 |  | 28,996 | 0,047 |
| 30 | 31 |  | C6 | C7 |  | FALSKT | 20-53569 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined | Undetermined |  |  |  |
| 32 | 33 |  | C8 | C9 |  | FALSKT | 20-53570 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 22,071 | 21,948 |  | 22,010 | 0,087 |
| 34 | 35 |  | C10 | C11 |  | FALSKT | 20-53575 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 30,067 | 30,118 |  | 30,092 | 0,036 |
| 36 | 37 |  | C12 | D1 |  | FALSKT | 20-53577 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined | Undetermined |  |  |  |
| 38 | 39 |  | D2 | D3 |  | FALSKT | 20-53584 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | 33,937 | 33,792 |  | 33,864 | 0,103 |
| 40 | 41 |  | D4 | D5 |  | FALSKT | 20-53585 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined | Undetermined |  |  |  |
| 42 | 43 |  | D6 | D7 |  | FALSKT | 20-53586 rdrp | xb | UNKNOWN | FAM | None | Undetermined | Undetermined |  |  |  |
| 44 | 45 | 46 | D8 | D9 | D10 | FALSKT | NTC rdrp | xb | NTC | FAM | None | Undetermined | Undetermined | Undetermined |  |  |

Comment: You could probably illustrate your issue with fewer columns.  Having to scroll horizontally to understand what you might mean by "duplicates" makes the question quite hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Data Flows dont offer any easy help for this requirement - key functionality needed is a running count to assign input rows to Well/Well2/Well3 etc.

I would tackle this upstream or downstream from SSIS, e.g. in SQL or Power Query.

Comment: Thank you, any ideas on how to do it in SQL?

Comment: If it's T-SQL, ROW_NUMBER function would give you the 1,2,3 on each row. Then it's a CASE statement for each output column. T-SQL does have PIVOT but I find it really ugly.